# JS/TS - Get Child Classes from Parent Class

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, oop, reflection

How to get child classes from parent class in JavaScript/TypeScript?

I found some other topic about it such as reflection and use of decorators, but I feel like they are an anti-pattern

Something like `Class.childClasses(ClassName)` that returns an array of child classes of ClassName

Comment: AFAIK, parent classes have no way to find out other classes that inherit it. You would need to manually add it to a static variable that holds an array on the parent whenever you create a new class that inherits from the parent.

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what you're asking for. "Get" child classes in what way? Assuming you could get them, what would your code do with it? Can you provide some example code of you using the code you wish existed?

Comment: @DanielKaplan Something like `Class.childClasses(ClassName)` that returns an array of child classes of ClassName

Comment: You would have to manually keep a list of child classes. As you say, it's an anti-pattern for the parent to know who inherits it.

Comment: @Kokodoko so either a manual array or reflection should be used, correct?

Comment: It really depends on your use case. You might be better off looking at the composition pattern. In this pattern a parent class HAS child classes. So then the parent always knows who is using what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vanilla TypeScript you are not able to do that. There is no reflection and there is no code connection from parent class to children classes; only the child has reference to its parent.

If you want to do that, you have to use one of the more advanced reflection tool. Here they are listed (mostly): https://github.com/akutruff/typescript-needs-types

Here is a StackBlitz [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rttist-find-inheritors?file=src%2Findex.ts) with alpha version of the [tst-reflect](https://github.com/Hookyns/tst-reflect).

```js
import 'rttist/typelib';
import { getType, Type, Metadata } from 'rttist';

class Parent {}

class Child1 extends Parent {}
class Child2 extends Parent {}
class ChildOfChild1 extends Child1 {}
class ChildOfChild2 extends Child2 {}

const parentType: Type = getType<Parent>();
const allInheritors = Metadata.getTypes().filter(
    (type) => type.isClass() && type.isSubclassOf(parentType)
);

console.log(allInheritors.map((t) => t.name));
```

output:

```
[ 'Child1', 'Child2', 'ChildOfChild1', 'ChildOfChild2' ]
```

Comment: What is _"native TypeScript"_?

Comment: TypeScript as is, without any plugins or additional tools.

Comment: "Vanilla" would be a better term I guess.